# symfony2 app.php the difference between debug parameter

Tags: symfony

i have a symfony2 project works well, after some modification of html, i always get a blank page when i set in app.php:

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
```

but if i set the debug parameter to true:

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', true);
```

everything works fine, i haven't see any log in my prod.log. I use php apc and fastCGI on my server. Anyone can tell me the difference between the parameter? Or this is just a problem of cache?

Comment: Check your Symfony, PHP and apache error logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally, i have found the problem. 
I searched again in my log of appache, i got this error:
[Fri Oct 26 14:12:19 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:  require() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'D:/workspace/symfony_bannieres/app/cache/devprod/doctrine/orm/Proxies\AcmeModerationBundleEntityModerationObjectStatusProxy.php' (include_path='.;d:\software\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.9\pear') in D:\workspace\symfony_bannieres\vendor\doctrine\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Proxy\ProxyFactory.php on line 85

ok, that means i do not have the entity proxy file. I check this file in the dev env, it exist. so i figure out which is a problem of my entity class. I found in my entity class where exists a un defined relationship,

```
 /**
 * @var AddepiUser
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AddepiUser")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="addepi_user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $addepiUser;
```

in fact i do not have this entity. so i removed this one and use

```
php app/console cache:warmup --env=prod --no-debug
```

to warm up the prod env. everything works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You say

> after some modification of html

is the reason for this? This absolutely not enough for us to help you solving your problem. Try to set

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(-1);
```

in your app.php file. At least there have to be error messages that you can provide.

Comment: cause i really do not know the reason. the only modification is the html code which is absolutely not the reason for the blank page.

Comment: what change did you do to the html?

Comment: I add the parameters in app.php and it works fine, even with debug=false, I checked the Apache log and symfony2 log, nothing appears. And then i removed the two line of display_errors, everything is fine. It's really strange.

Comment: just merged two layout to one layout, anyway, just a twig file. after this the website is totally blocked, always error 500.

Comment: ah, the only thing i have done is this morning i restart the fastCGI for another site.

Comment: found a similar problem http://forum.symfony-project.org/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=38028 however the modification of app.php file seems to be the solutions

Comment: thanks a lot, you help me even i do not figure out what happens.